# Configurable Product Collection and variants

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product, collection, catalog

Is there any way I can fetch all the variants of a configurable products from a product collection in Magento 2? Thanks!

I would like to return the products including the attribute options and and child products as well. So far, I have the code from \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository::getList()

```
public function getList(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria)
{
    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection */
    $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
    $this->extensionAttributesJoinProcessor->process($collection);

    foreach ($this->metadataService->getList($this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create())->getItems() as $metadata) {
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect($metadata->getAttributeCode());
    }
    $collection->joinAttribute('status', 'catalog_product/status', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');
    $collection->joinAttribute('visibility', 'catalog_product/visibility', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');

    //Add filters from root filter group to the collection
    foreach ($searchCriteria->getFilterGroups() as $group) {
        $this->addFilterGroupToCollection($group, $collection);
    }
    /** @var SortOrder $sortOrder */
    foreach ((array)$searchCriteria->getSortOrders() as $sortOrder) {
        $field = $sortOrder->getField();
        $collection->addOrder(
            $field,
            ($sortOrder->getDirection() == SortOrder::SORT_ASC) ? 'ASC' : 'DESC'
        );
    }
    $collection->setCurPage($searchCriteria->getCurrentPage());
    $collection->setPageSize($searchCriteria->getPageSize());
    $collection->load();

    $searchResult = $this->searchResultsFactory->create();
    $searchResult->setSearchCriteria($searchCriteria);
    $searchResult->setItems($collection->getItems());
    $searchResult->setTotalCount($collection->getSize());
    return $searchResult;
}
```

However, this collection does not retrieve the attribute options from configurable products.

Comment: in Magento1 or Magento2?

Comment: in Magento 2 sir. Sorry just updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
<?php 

protected $productRepository;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    ...
}

public function execute()
{
    $id = 1; // Configurable Product ID
    $product = $this->productRepository->getById($id);


    // \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable
    $assoProducts = $product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($product);


    // Retrieve used product attributes
    $variantsUsed = $product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProductAttributes($product);

}
```

You may be interested in some below functions

```
getUsedProductAttributeIds() // Retrieve identifiers of used product attributes
getParentIdsByChild() // Retrieve parent ids array by required child
getConfigurableAttributes() // Retrieve configurable attributes data
getConfigurableAttributesAsArray() // Retrieve Configurable Attributes as array
getUsedProductIds() // retrieve subproducts identifiers
```

For More you can refer the model class

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/ffea3cd/app/code/Magento/ConfigurableProduct/Model/Product/Type/Configurable.php

Comment: Thanks! this is a great help. But can this configurable options be extended in the to the collection? \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository::getList() ?

Comment: You can call the list and filter configurable product type from it. Then in loop you can use the above logic. I don't think you can directly extend list to get for all.